# Multi level meta-analysis model

Tags: multilevel-analysis, meta-analysis

[image]

I'm working on meta-analysis in the agricultural sciences.

I have four groups a, b, c, d which are nested within each study.
One paper can have multiple studies and each study may have data from different Crops.

The structure looks like (in the attached image).
Please notice that study 1 paper 1 is different from study 1 paper 2,  but crop 1 is the same for all studies. I am interested in comparing the four groups.

Following a previous post, I got this model:

data$Study.in.Paper <- paste0(data$Paper, ".", data$Study)
fit <- rma.mv (yi, vi, mods = ~ group - 1, random = list (~ group | study.in.paper, ~ group | paper), data = data, struct = "HCS")*

**mods** group because I am interested in model results to get an estimate for each group
**random** this allows random variation between studies (~ 1 | Paper) and within each study (~ 1 | Study.in.Paper)

I would like to know if this code is accurate based on the described structure.
and, should I include Crops in the model or no?

Sorry for the long question

Thanks in advance